# How to upload a file in Titanium

Tags: rest, api, upload, titanium, appcelerator

I have and app in Titanium and I'm using https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi to handle my requests to the rest api, now I need to upload a file to the server. How can I manage that?

This is possible to be done using the RESTAPI Adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used that library if you can/want to use a different REST library you can have a look at https://github.com/jasonkneen/RESTe library

I use this for all my API calls and you can POST any data with it.

```
api.postData({
    body: {
        text: "Test data",
        file: Ti.Filesystem.getFile().read()
    }
}, function(data) {
    // response data
});
```

It also has some Model/Collection helpers:
https://github.com/jasonkneen/RESTe#alloy-collections-and-model-support